# Cant open executable files generated by CLion

Tags: c++, exe, clion

I am using Clion and i have got problem with exe files.
When I try to open exe file, I got warning that i don't have **libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll** and **libstdc++-6.dll** and I can not open this file. 
I do not have any ideas how to fix this. I have read about it, but i can't really understand whats going on with this **-static** import. I hope question is clear!

Comment: ***I do not have any ideas how to fix this*** put these files in the same folder as your executable. Or adjust your `PATH` environment variable so that these files are in your system path.

Comment: When i put this to same folder i got another error and i do not really know how to set up this PATH

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm